# Get Parent attribute values xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file like this

> < insrtuction name=inst1>
>
> < destnation >
>   < connection> con1
>   < /connection> 
>   < /destination>
>
> < destnation >
>   < connection> con2
>   < /connection> 
>   < /destination>
>
> < /instruction>
>
> < insrtuction name=inst2>
>
> < destnation >
>   < connection> con3
>   < /connection> 
>   < /destination>
>
> < destnation >
>   < connection> con4
>   < /connection> 
>   < /destination>
>
> < /instruction>

I have to get all the connections. code I wrote

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("D:\\connections.xml");
        string text = "";
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/instruction/destination");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string configuration = xn["connection"].InnerText;               
            text = text + configuration + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
        }
        textBox1.Text=text;
    }
```

Output I am getting is

```
con1
con2
con3
con4
```

According to my new requirement output should be

```
Instruction Name : inst1
connection: con1
connection: con1
Instruction Name : inst2
connection: con3
connection: con4
```

I am new to .net, I am using 2.0 frame work, I cant use LINQ. Thanks

Comment: what are difficulties you encounter ?

Comment: @Steve B  I was trying to do like this 
string instruction = xn["Instruction"].GetElementsByTagName("name").ToString();
but its throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write this :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("D:\\connections.xml");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/instruction");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(xn.Attribute["name"].Value);
        foreach(XmlNode subNodes in xn.SelectNodes("destination/connection") {
            sb.AppendLine(subNodes.InnerText);
        }
    }
    textBox1.Text=sb.ToString();
}
```

However, I think this a very easy case you could have solved yourself. There is no technical challenge here. I advise you to take a training, read a book and dive into the documentation.

**PS:** not the use of [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of string concatenation...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. one small correction, in the inner foreach loop in should be subNodes.InnerText instead of  subNodes.Text

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
    xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load("D:\\connections.xml");
    string val="";
    string text = "";
    foreach (XmlNode child in xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(child.Name + ": " + child.InnerText.ToString());
                node = child.Name; //here you will get node name
                if (node.Equals("Instruction"))
                {
                    val = child.InnerText.ToString(); //value of the node
                    //MessageBox.Show(node + ": " + val);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, with an inner loop:

```
        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/instruction");
        foreach (XmlElement xn in xnList)
        {
            text += "Instruction Name : " + xn.GetAttribute("name") + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (XmlElement cn in xn.SelectNodes("connection"))
            {
                text += "Connection : " + xn.InnerText + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```